# How to extract only network indicators from the stings in sample?

Tags: python, regex, http, batch-file, ip

I have a sample with potential malware behaviour, i want to reveal all the network indicators like website names and ip addresses which it is connecting to.

By using strings output i got

```
    $ strings 6787c54e6a2c5cffd1576dcdc8c4f42c954802b7
    %PDF-1.5
    1 0 obj
    <</Type/Page/Parent 80 0 R/Contents 36 0 R/MediaBox[0 0 612 792]/Annots[2 0 R 4 0 R 6 0 R 8 0 R 10 0 R 12 0 R 14 0 R 16 0 R 18 0 R]/Group 20 0 R/StructParents 1/Tabs/S/Resources<</Font<</F1 21 0 R/F2 23 0 R/F3 26 0 R/F4 29 0 R/F5 31 0 R>>/XObject<</Image6 33 0 R/Image9 34 0 R>>>>>>
    endobj
    2 0 obj
    <</Type/Annot/Subtype/Link/Rect[139.10001 398.20001 449.84 726.20001]/Border[0 0 0]/F 4/NM(PDFE-48D407B4789BA8880)/P 1 0 R/StructParent 0/A 3 0 R>>
    endobj
    3 0 obj
    <</S/URI/URI(http://www.pdfupdatersacrobat.top/website/hts-cache/index.php?userid=info@narainsfashionfabrics.com)>>
    endobj
    4 0 obj
    <</Type/Annot/Subtype/Link/Rect[232.39999 618.03003 370.14999 629.53003]/Border[0 0 0]/F 4/NM(PDFE-48D407B4789BA8881)/P 1 0 R/StructParent 2/A 5 0 R>>
    endobj
    5 0 obj
    <</S/URI/URI(>>
    endobj
    6 0 obj
    <</Type/Annot/Subtype/Link/Rect[278.87 583.20001 324.88 594.13]/Border[0 0 0]/F 4/NM(PDFE-48D407B4789BA8882)/P 1 0 R/StructParent 3/A 7 0 R>>
    endobj
    7 0 obj
    <</S/URI/URI()>>
    endobj
    8 0 obj
    <</Type/Annot/Subtype/Link/Rect[185.75999 377.28 398.16 733.67999]/Border[0 0 0]/C[0 0 0]/F 4/NM(PDFE-48D4183FB09C5EC13)/P 1 0 R/A 9 0 R/H/N>>
    endobj
    9 0 obj
    <</S/URI/URI(http://sajiye.net/file/website/file/main/index.php?userid=alwaha_alghannaa@hotmail.com)>>
    endobj
    10 0 obj
    <</Type/Annot/Subtype/Link/Rect[185.75999 373.67999 398.88 734.40002]/Border[0 0 0]/C[0 0 0]/F 4/NM(PDFE-48D4183FB09C5EC14)/P 1 0 R/A 11 0 R/H/N>>
    endobj
    11 0 obj
    <</S/URI/URI(http://sajiye.net/file/website/file/main/index.php?userid=kitja@siamdee2558.com)>>
    endobj
    12 0 obj
    <</Type/Annot/Subtype/Link/Rect[132.48 0 474.48001 772.56]/Border[0 0 0]/C[0 0 0]/F 4/NM(PDFE-48D460B5879C4D8C5)/P 1 0 R/A 13 0 R/H/N>>
    endobj
    13 0 obj
    <</S/URI/URI(http://nurking.pl/wp-admin/user/email.163.htm?login=)>>
    endobj
    14 0 obj
    <</Type/Annot/Subtype/Link/Rect[0 0 612 792]/Border[0 0 0]/C[0 0 0]/F 4/NM(PDFE-48D465334C760A446)/P 1 0 R/A 15 0 R/H/N>>
    endobj
    15 0 obj
    <</S/URI/URI(https://www.dropbox.com/s/76jr9jzg020gory/Swift%20Copy.uue?dl=1)>>
    endobj
    16 0 obj
    <</Type/Annot/Subtype/Link/Rect[.72 0 612 789.84003]/Border[0 0 0]/C[0 0 0]/F 4/NM(PDFE-48D4C7F946F3F02B7)/P 1 0 R/A 17 0 R/H/N>>
    endobj
    17 0 obj
    <</S/URI/URI(https://www.dropbox.com/s/28aaqjdradyy4io/Swift-Copy_pdf.uue?dl=1)>>
    endobj
    18 0 obj
    <</Type/Annot/Subtype/Link/Rect[0 5.76 612 792]/Border[0 0 0]/C[0 0 0]/F 4/P 1 0 R/A 19 0 R/H/N>>
    endobj
    19 0 obj
    <</S/URI/URI(https://www.dropbox.com/s/d71h5a56r16u3f0/swift_copy.jar?dl=1)>>
    endobj
    20 0 obj
    <</S/Transparency/CS/DeviceRGB>>
    endobj
    21 0 obj
    <</Type/Font/Subtype/TrueType/BaseFont/TimesNewRoman/FirstChar 32/LastChar 252/Encoding/WinAnsiEncoding/FontDescriptor 22 0 R/Widths[250 333 408 500 500 833 777 180 333 333 500 563 250 333 250 277 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 277 277 563 563 563 443 920 722 666 666 722 610 556 722 722 333 389 722 610 889 722 722 556 722 666 556 610 722 722 943 722 722 610 333 277 333 469 500 333 443 500 443 500 443 333 500 500 277 277 500 277 777 500 500 500 500 333 389 277 500 500 722 500 500 443 479 200 479 541 350 500 350 333 500 443 1000 500 500 333 1000 556 333 889 350 610 350 350 333 333 443 443 350 500 1000 333 979 389 333 722 350 443 722 250 333 500 500 500 500 200 500 333 759 275 500 563 333 759 500 399 548 299 299 333 576 453 333 333 299 310 500 750 750 750 443 722 722 722 722 722 722 889 666 610 610 610 610 333 333 333 333 722 722 722 722 722 722 722 563 722 722 722 722 722 722 556 500 443 443 443 443 443 443 666 443 443 443 443 443 277 277 277 277 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 548 500 500 500 500 500]>>
    endobj
    22 0 obj
    <</Type/FontDescriptor/FontName/TimesNewRoman/Flags 32/FontBBox[-568 -215 2045 891]/FontFamily(Times New Roman)/FontWeight 400/Ascent 891/CapHeight 693/Descent -215/MissingWidth 777/StemV 0/ItalicAngle 0/XHeight 485>>
    endobj
    23 0 obj
    <</Type/Font/Subtype/TrueType/BaseFont/ABCDEE+Calibri,BoldItalic/FirstChar 32/LastChar 117/Name/F2/Encoding/WinAnsiEncoding/FontDescriptor 24 0 R/Widths[226 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 630 0 459 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 668 532 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 528 0 412 0 491 316 0 0 246 0 0 246 804 527 527 0 0 0 0 347 527]>>
    endobj
    24 0 obj
    <</Type/FontDescriptor/FontName/ABCDEE+Calibri,BoldItalic/FontWeight 700/Flags 32/FontBBox[-691 -250 1265 750]/Ascent 750/CapHeight 750/Descent -250/StemV 53/ItalicAngle -11/AvgWidth 536/MaxWidth 1956/XHeight 250/FontFile2 25 0 R>>
    endobj
<</Type/Pages/Count 1/Kids[1 0 R]>>
endobj
81 0 obj
<</Type/Catalog/Pages 80 0 R/Lang(en-US)/MarkInfo<</Marked true>>/Metadata 83 0 R/StructTreeRoot 37 0 R>>
endobj
82 0 obj
<</Producer(RAD PDF 2.36.8.0 - http://www.radpdf.com)/Author(alesk)/Creator(RAD PDF)/RadPdfCustomData(pdfescape.com-open-AC00E8D5A4B4C84BC37A2054F4EC794B0297765728CB8415)/CreationDate(D:20160825075202+01'00')/ModDate(D:20170711012532-08'00')>>
endobj
83 0 obj
<</Type/Metadata/Subtype/XML/Length 1031>>stream
<?xpacket begin="
" id="W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d"?>
<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="DynaPDF 4.0.11.30, http://www.dynaforms.com">
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
<rdf:Description rdf:about=""
        xmlns:pdf="http://ns.adobe.com/pdf/1.3/"
        xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
        xmlns:xmp="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/"
        xmlns:xmpMM="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/mm/">
<pdf:Producer>RAD PDF 2.36.8.0 - http://www.radpdf.com</pdf:Producer>
<xmp:CreateDate>2016-08-25T07:52:02+01:00</xmp:CreateDate>
<xmp:CreatorTool>RAD PDF</xmp:CreatorTool>
<xmp:MetadataDate>2017-07-11T01:25:32-08:00</xmp:MetadataDate>
<xmp:ModifyDate>2017-07-11T01:25:32-08:00</xmp:ModifyDate>
<dc:creator><rdf:Seq><rdf:li xml:lang="x-default">alesk</rdf:li></rdf:Seq></dc:creator>
<xmpMM:DocumentID>uuid:a184332f-8592-38c8-908c-45914e523218</xmpMM:DocumentID>
<xmpMM:VersionID>1</xmpMM:VersionID>
<xmpMM:RenditionClass>default</xmpMM:RenditionClass>
</rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
</x:xmpmeta>
<?xpacket end="w"?>
endstream
endobj
84 0 obj
<</Type/XRef/Size 85/Root 81 0 R/Info 82 0 R/ID[<299C21286E590F03363518EFD9FBBF99><299C21286E590F03363518EFD9FBBF99>]/W[1 3 0]/Filter/FlateDecode/Length 239>>stream
cx?{
endstream
endobj
startxref
204273
%%EOF
```

So is there any way to digest all these strings and extract only network indicators like domains or IP addresses using any regex or any other method.

Suggestions are welcome

**Output Expected:**

```
http://www.pdfupdatersacrobat.top/website/hts-cache/index.php?userid=info@narainsfashionfabrics.com
http://sajiye.net/file/website/file/main/index.php?userid=alwaha_alghannaa@hotmail.com
http://ns.adobe.com/pdf/1.3/
```

Comment: So, you want a [tag:batch-file] to regex your strings?

Comment: Yes a single regex which i can pass this input which will give network indicators

Comment: Okay - It's possible in batch. But you know how Stack Overflow works. You need to show your effort

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. You can find all URLs and then extract them using back references. You can read more about back-references [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html).

```
# Pattern describing regular expression
pattern = re.compile(r'(\(https?[:_%A-Z=?/a-z0-9.-]+\))') 

# List where we store all URLs
urls = []

# For each invoice pattern you find in string, append it to list
for url in pattern.finditer(string):
    urls.append(url.group(1))
```

**Note:**

You should use `pattern.finditter()` because that way you can iterate trough all pattern findings in text you called `string`. From *re.finditer* documentation:

> re.finditer(pattern, string, flags=0) 
>   Return an iterator yielding
>   MatchObject instances over all non-overlapping matches for the RE
>   pattern in string. The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches
>   are returned in the order found. Empty matches are included in the
>   result unless they touch the beginning of another match.

Answer (score 0):

As findstr only offers rudimentary RegEx functionality I suggest using PowerShell

(if necessary wrapped in a batch)

This rather course RegEx doesn't strip the tail of the http lines:

```
> gc .\sample.txt |sls '^.*?(https?:\/\/.*)$'|%{$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value}
http://www.pdfupdatersacrobat.top/website/hts-cache/index.php?userid=info@narainsfashionfabrics.com)>>
http://sajiye.net/file/website/file/main/index.php?userid=alwaha_alghannaa@hotmail.com)>>
http://sajiye.net/file/website/file/main/index.php?userid=kitja@siamdee2558.com)>>
http://nurking.pl/wp-admin/user/email.163.htm?login=)>>
https://www.dropbox.com/s/76jr9jzg020gory/Swift%20Copy.uue?dl=1)>>
https://www.dropbox.com/s/28aaqjdradyy4io/Swift-Copy_pdf.uue?dl=1)>>
https://www.dropbox.com/s/d71h5a56r16u3f0/swift_copy.jar?dl=1)>>
http://www.radpdf.com)/Author(alesk)/Creator(RAD PDF)/RadPdfCustomData(pdfescape.com-open-AC00E8D5A4B4C84BC37A2054F4EC794B0297765728CB8415)/CreationDate(D:20160825075202+01'00')/ModDate(D:20170711012532-08'00')>>
http://www.dynaforms.com">
http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
http://ns.adobe.com/pdf/1.3/"
http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/"
http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/mm/">
http://www.radpdf.com</pdf:Producer>
```

---

Likewise coarse for the possible IPs

```
> gc .\sample.txt |sls '^(.*?(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}.*)$'|%{$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value}
<</Producer(RAD PDF 2.36.8.0 - http://www.radpdf.com)/Author(alesk)/Creator(RAD PDF)/RadPdfCustomData(pdfescape.com-open-AC00E8D5A4B4C84BC37A2054F4EC794B0297765728CB8415)/CreationDate(D:20160825075202+01'00')/ModDate(D:20170711012532-08'00')>>
<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="DynaPDF 4.0.11.30, http://www.dynaforms.com">
<pdf:Producer>RAD PDF 2.36.8.0 - http://www.radpdf.com</pdf:Producer>
```

```
Aliases used:  
gc  = Get-Content  
sls = Select-String  
%   = ForEach-Object
```